# How can an open file be reverted in the new Gedit?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gedit

What is the new equivalent of the revert command in the old Gedit File menu? The changes were done in another program. I want to quickly revert the changes done to the file from the disk to load the changes using a keyboard shortcut or menu accelerator.

I want to make it clear that I do not want to recover the original contents of the file. I want to easily load the new modified contents into Gedit.

Comment: I think there is no new equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.  +1 for a good question with a simple answer (unfortunately, probably not what you wanted....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting answer after your edit:

As the Gnome project is aiming for simplicity, they're removing existing functionality that already exists in another way, so File-Open does that and has always done that: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to make it clear that I do not want to recover the original contents of the file. I want to easily load the new modified content into gedit. I apologize if I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: You mean a simple File-Open??? @Timo